# How to make RubyMine use already-running docker-compose service, rather than trying to start it?

Tags: docker-compose, rubymine

I'm using docker-compose on a Rails project, with the main web service being called `web`.

When I try to run a test from RubyMine, it attempts to run

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f 
/Users/jy/Development/@Rails/project/docker-compose.yml -f 
/Users/jy/Library/Caches/RubyMine2018.3/tmp/docker-compose.override.35.yml 
up --exit-code-from web --abort-on-container-exit web
```

Even though the web container is already up.

This leads to issues with duplicate networks being created, and the `web` service being stopped afterward thanks to the `--abort-on-container-exit`.

How can I make RubyMine run my tests using a simple `docker-compose exec web bundle exec rspec …`, without all the preamble? I *know* that command works because it works from the command line (but running an individual test involves a *lot* of typing to fill in `--example testname`!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it doesn't support this yet.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19849 is the issue that needs resolving in order to make it work properly.